# Stuck on Downloading Javascript Bundle 100% - Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I guess that I've tried every solution that exists on the internet about this issue, and nothing works, and I don't even know where to look anymore. It started to happen from nowhere and I can't even open the app settings shaking the phone, it's completely stuck on this screen.

I cleaned up NPM, Yarn, Expo's caches and disabled the Remote Dev Tools.

I would be so much thankful for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try reverting to your last known working commit, then incrementally adding back the changes until this happens again. This often is a result of delaying hiding the splash screen (perhaps via AppLoading or SplashScreen) and then not hiding it because of some error in the app code preventing the code to hide it from being called.

Comment: I am having this issue in a basic expo init app. How can I solve this?

Comment: @SuryaMahla - by "basic expo init app" do you mean completely unchanged from the blank template that you initialized? you can post more info to https://github.com/expo/expo/issues if so. please follow the issue template

Comment: @SuryaMahla What worked for me on a basic init app was exiting iOS simulator completely, Similuator -> Quit Simulator. Then terminating expo process and running expo again with `expo start`, then entering `i` to get Expo to start iOS simulator and viola no more `Downloading JavaScript bundle 100%`

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was due to the a remote debugger.

I left the remote debugging on, put the mac in sleep and when I turned it on again the iOS Simulator remained stuck at bundling 100%, irrespective of what I've tried (kill simulator, expo r -c, Reload app, etc.)

However, I could have realized the root cause earlier because on the physical device it was working the entire time.

Hope this saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

Try Disable **Debug Remote JS** in the IOS Simulator
by clicking ctrl + cmd +Z on Mac

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something is wrong with the dependencies, just close down the react-native environment ( android studio) and your IDE, just closing and restarting may work if not, check for updates or delete and reinstall your dependencies ( expo i )

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.